# Loading txt to matlab - multiple headers in the file

Tags: matlab, file, load

I have .txt file with operational data. It contains "blocks" with time data - all in one file.

```
Time    Value   ID  
2YC010: I-134-o {L100} [Bq/l]   
29.10.2014 22:31:00 22550   
31.10.2014 00:02:00 22020   
31.10.2014 23:07:00 19130   
01.11.2014 23:21:00 22000   
03.11.2014 00:26:00 20640   
...

Time    Value   ID  
2YC010: Cs-137-o {L100} [Bq/l]  
29.10.2014 22:31:00 1648    
31.10.2014 00:02:00 1448    
31.10.2014 23:07:00 1803    
01.11.2014 23:21:00 1546    
...
```

How can I load each block to appropriate variable (including name and units). All tutorials I have found were considering just one header, not another header hidden somewhere inside the file.
thanks

Comment: Read line by line with `fgets` and parse. Matlab is not a magical box, sometimes you have to do some work when using non-standard stuff..

Comment: Are your data chunks uniformly sized?

Comment: unfortunately not, the "format" is the same but the number of rows is different

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `importdata` (http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)